# Any prerequisites for EffectComposer to outline meshes?

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm trying to highlight my meshes when hovered on. I've read the docs, then tried few examples I found online. Nothing seems to work.
My mesh is loaded from .fbx (also tried with primitives with the same effect)

My component return:

```
return (
        <Selection>
            <EffectComposer multisampling={8} autoClear={false}>
                <Outline blur visibleEdgeColor="red" edgeStrength={100} width={500} />
            </EffectComposer>
        {assetsList.map((asset) => {
        if(asset.visible) {
            return ( 
                    <Select enabled={highlighted} key={asset.id}>
                        <mesh
                            onPointerOver={() => setHighlighted(true)} 
                            onPointerOut={() => setHighlighted(false)}
                            castShadow = {asset.castShadow}
                            receiveShadow = {asset.receiveShadow}
                            geometry={nodes.Aset_food_fruit_S_tezbbgrra_LOD0.geometry}
                            material={nodes.Aset_food_fruit_S_tezbbgrra_LOD0.material}
                            position={asset.position}
                            rotation={asset.rotation}
                            scale={asset.scale}
                        />
                    </Select>
                );
            }
        return;
        })}
        </Selection>
    );
}
```

this is later called in Canvas comp.

onPointerOver and onPointerOut are executing correctly, but still it seems that EffectComposer is not triggering. At some point I even copied it into someone's else code sandbox example and it worked. No idea why though. No compile errors, imports look ok too